# Dynamically generate XML with attributes and child nodes from Map in Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

Given a Groovy Map of indeterminate depth, with each level having both an "attributes" and "elements" key, I'm looking for a way to recursively build an XML from this map:

```
       Map map = [
            root: [
                    elements  : [
                            node1: [
                                    elements  : [
                                            key1Node1: "elementValue1Node1",
                                            key2Node1: "elementValue2Node2",
                                    ],
                                    attributes: [
                                            attribute1Node1: "attributeValue1node1",
                                            attribute2Node1: "attributeValue2node1",
                                            attribute3Node1: "attributeValue3node1"
                                    ]
                            ],
                            node2: [
                                    elements  : [
                                            key1Node2: "elementValue1Node2",
                                            key2Node2: "elementValue2Node2",
                                    ],
                                    attributes: [
                                            attribute1Node2: "attributeValue1node2",
                                            attribute2Node2: "attributeValue2node2",
                                            attribute3Node2: "attributeValue3node2"
                                    ]
                            ]
                    ],
                    attributes: [
                            rootAttribute: "iniciarSesion"
                    ]
            ]

    ]
```

The resulting XML should look like this:

```
<root rootAttribute="rootValue">
    <node1 attribute1Node1="attributeValue1node1" attribute2Node1="attributeValue2node1" attribute3Node1="attributeValue3node1">
        <key1Node1>elementValue1Node1</key1Node1>
        <key2Node1>elementValue2Node2</key2Node1>
    </node1>
    <node2 attribute1Node1="attributeValue1node2" attribute2Node1="attributeValue2node2" attribute3Node1="attributeValue3node2">
        <key1Node2>elementValue1Node2"</key1Node2>
        <key2Node2>elementValue2Node2</key2Node2>
    </node2>
</root>
```

So far I've tried using a method that can traverse the object and add the necessary nodes at every turn. The Groovy [documentation for markupBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-latest/html/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilder.html#createNode-java.lang.Object-java.util.Map-) shows that the createNode method can be take a map of attributes and an object for the value. So I've attempted the following:

```
static def makeXmlBody(map) {
    def writer = new StringWriter()
    def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)

    map.each {
        k, v ->
            if (v.getClass() == LinkedHashMap) {
                xml.createNode(k, v.attributes, makeXmlBody(v.elements))
                println(writer)

            } else {
                xml.createNode(k, v)
                println(writer)
            }
    }
}
```

The thinking is that if the value is a map it must have "elements" and "attributes" in it. Therefore we can pass the field key as the first parameter, the node's "attributes" map as the second and a recursive call to the same function as the third, so that every level will be built.

Issue is that it seems each level leaves each level below untouched, so in the output (see the two printlns in the code), I see each level being done (somewhat) correctly, but the final result isn't useful.

```
<key1Node1>elementValue1Node1
<key1Node1>elementValue1Node1
  <key2Node1>elementValue2Node2
<node1 attribute1Node1='attributeValue1node1' attribute2Node1='attributeValue2node1' attribute3Node1='attributeValue3node1'>{key1Node1=elementValue1Node1, key2Node1=elementValue2Node2}
<key1Node2>elementValue1Node2
<key1Node2>elementValue1Node2
  <key2Node2>elementValue2Node2
<node1 attribute1Node1='attributeValue1node1' attribute2Node1='attributeValue2node1' attribute3Node1='attributeValue3node1'>{key1Node1=elementValue1Node1, key2Node1=elementValue2Node2}
  <node2 attribute1Node2='attributeValue1node2' attribute2Node2='attributeValue2node2' attribute3Node2='attributeValue3node2'>{key1Node2=elementValue1Node2, key2Node2=elementValue2Node2}
<root rootAttribute='iniciarSesion'>{node1={elements={key1Node1=elementValue1Node1, key2Node1=elementValue2Node2}, attributes={attribute1Node1=attributeValue1node1, attribute2Node1=attributeValue2node1, attribute3Node1=attributeValue3node1}}, node2={elements={key1Node2=elementValue1Node2, key2Node2=elementValue2Node2}, attributes={attribute1Node2=attributeValue1node2, attribute2Node2=attributeValue2node2, attribute3Node2=attributeValue3node2}}}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after a couple hours of struggle, it seems this will go to any depth of nested maps and build the XML. Probably not the most Kosher code I've seem, but it will do.

```
static def makeXmlBody(map, lastParent, counter) {
    def writer = new StringWriter()
    def xmlBuilder = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
    if (counter == 0) {
        xmlBuilder.mkp.xmlDeclaration(version: "1.0", encoding: "utf-8")
    }
    counter++

    map.each {
        if (it.value.getClass() == LinkedHashMap) {
            xmlBuilder.createNode(it.key, it.value.attributes, makeXmlBody(it.value.elements, lastParent, counter))
            xmlBuilder.nodeCompleted(lastParent, it.key)
            lastParent = it.key
        } else {

            xmlBuilder.createNode(it.key, it.value)
            xmlBuilder.nodeCompleted(lastParent, it.key)
        }
    }
    return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(writer.toString())
}
```

Use

```
makeXmlBody(map, null, 0)
```

Output (prettified)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<root rootAttribute='rootAttribute1'>
    <node1 attribute1Node1='attributeValue1node1' attribute2Node1='attributeValue2node1'
           attribute3Node1='attributeValue3node1'>
        <key1Node1>elementValue1Node1</key1Node1>
        <key2Node1>elementValue2Node2</key2Node1>
    </node1>
    <node2 attribute1Node2='attributeValue1node2' attribute2Node2='attributeValue2node2'
           attribute3Node2='attributeValue3node2'>
        <key1Node2>elementValue1Node2</key1Node2>
        <key2Node2>elementValue2Node2</key2Node2>
    </node2>
</root>
```